# Rake function does not work with random user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im want to create a simple rake function which provides me with the option to draw a random user.

```
task :pick_winner => :environment do
 user = User.find(:first, :order => 'RAND()')
 puts "Winner #{user.name}"
end
```

When i run code above I get the following error however

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Users with 'id': (first, {:order=>"RAND()"}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

What goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like old Rails.

Try:

```
User.order('RAND()').first
```

Comment: But then this should work in rails c right? So if i do u = User.order('RAND()').first it should work? Now i get an error....

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: That is, `RAND()` I think is MySQL. For postgres, you have to do `User.order('random()').first`